# Which Marvel character has the most alternate versions?

Tags: marvel, comics

Most Marvel characters have at least one, but many popular characters have many more. Who has the most named alternative versions,named, preferably.

Comment: I'd suggest that with the spider-verse and spider-gheddon events, spider-man probably takes the cake by a long shot but I don't have actual numbers so not posting this as an answer

Comment: Do you want 'most alternate versions', or 'most commonly-known alternate versions'? In short, why does it matter if they are obscure?

Comment: I've voted to close as unclear. In-universe each person (with a couple of exceptions) has a nearly infinite number of alternates.

Comment: I mean alternative versions. I just meant that there are a lot of obscure ones, and I wondered which one had the most, obscure or not. I will edit the question.

Comment: When you say "named alternate version", are you including different versions (from alternative universes) that share the same name? For example, the Spider-Man in the Raimi films isn't the same Spider-Man from the (superior, imho) Spider-Man and his Amazing Friends cartoon.

Comment: If it he/she a different name, but is meant as an alternate, even if he or she has different powers. i.e., Spiderman Noir. He has different powers, a different origin, and is called different nicknames, but he is still Spiderman.

Comment: I've voted to reopen. The answer is Spider-Man (obviously) but hopefully someone (not me) will put in the effort to track you down a list.

Comment: I'm not going to ask questions anymore. I seem to just get downvoted, and never get any sort of answer.

Comment: @Com10burnsaway - Your other question has a nice answer, even if people didn't much like the question itself. This one, on the other hand, is overly broad and poorly scoped.

Comment: Okie dokie, buckaroo.

Answer (score 2):

I would say Spider-man:

- [Old Man Spider (Earth-4)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Ezekiel_Sims_(Earth-4))
- [Penelope Parker (Earth-11)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Penelope_Parker_(Earth-11))
- [Captain Universe (Earth-13)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-13))
- [The Spider (Earth-15)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-15))
- [Ben Reilly (Earth-94)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Ben_Reilly_(Earth-94))
- [Peter Parquagh (Earth-311)](https://www.marvel.com/characters/peter-parquagh-earth-311)
- [Spider-Man (Earth-616)](https://www.marvel.com/characters/spider-man-peter-parker/in-comics/profile)
- [Spider-UK (Earth-833)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-UK)
- [Wild Card (Earth-982)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-982))
- [Spider-Cat (Earth-999)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Cat_(Earth-999))
- [Spider-Man (Earth-1048)](https://store.playstation.com/en-us/product/UP9000-CUSA02299_00-MARVELSSPIDERMAN)
- [Man-Spider (Earth-1298)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-1298))
- [Ultimate Spider-Man (Earth-1610)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Spider-Man)
- [Spider-Man (Earth-1967)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(1967_TV_series))
- [Spider-Man (Earth-1983)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_and_His_Amazing_Friends)
- [Zombie Spider-Man (Earth-2149)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-2149))
- [Cyborg Spider-Man (Earth-2818)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-2818))
- [Spider-Monkey (Earth-8101)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-8101))
- [Spider-Ham (Earth-8311)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Ham)
- [Spiders-Man (Earth-11580)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spiders-Man_(Earth-11580))
- [Peter Parker (Earth-12041)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_Spider-Man_(TV_series))
- [Spider-Wolf (Earth-13989)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Wolf_(Earth-13989))
- [Peni Parker (Earth-14512)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peni_Parker)
- [Web-Slinger (Earth-31913)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-31913))
- [Spider-Demon (Earth-32081)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Spider-Demon_(Earth-32081))
- [Spider-Man: India (Earth-50101)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man:_India)
- [Supaidaman (Earth-51778)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Takuya_Yamashiro_(Earth-51778))
- [Spider (Earth-80827)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-80827))
- [Spider-Man Noir (Earth-90214)](https://www.marvel.com/characters/spider-man-noir)
- [Spider-Man (Earth-199999)](https://www.marvel.com/characters/spider-man-peter-parker/on-screen/profile)
- [Spider-Man (Earth-312500)](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Peter_Parker_(Earth-312500))

This list is by no means complete, I'll continue to update it.
For right now, I'm counting Kaine and Morales as separate characters.